# How to calculate "scanLegth" param from Bitmap.getRGB565(...)

Tags: java, blackberry

I'm trying get bytes from bitmap in blackberry using the next method in Bitmap:

```
getRGB565(byte[] rgbData, int offset, int scanLength, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

But i have read the params and i don't know how must i calculate scanLength:

> scanLength - Width of a scanline (in bytes) within the data array.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `scanLength` is the full width of the original image, while `width` is the width of the rectangle you are copying from.

If you are copying the whole image it is the same, but if you are copying only a part of the image you'll have `scanLength > width`.

See also [the Bitmap#getRGB565 javadoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Bitmap.html#getRGB565%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

To get byte[] from Bitmap I used this: http://blackberry-digger.blogspot.com/2009/05/code-convert-bitmap-to-png-and-then.html and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry it was too easy . In getARG is another example , it must be used usually with the same `int width` param